# Getting SQL string from LINQ to EF query

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

What is the most efficient way to get the sql query from EF? I need this so I can run the query analysis and find its execution plan.

I know I can hook profiler to SQL server, but this step is a pain and a tremendous hit on productivity, almost enough to give up ORM altogether.

Is there a better, more efficient way to optimize EF queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better, more efficient way to optimize EF queries?

Yes, buy [EF Profiler](http://efprof.com/) or [Huagati Profiler](http://www.huagati.com/l2sprofiler/). Alternatively use [EF Provider wrapper](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32) for tracing.

> I know I can hook profiler to SQL server, but this step is a pain and
>   a tremendous hit on productivity, almost enough to give up ORM
>   altogether.

Profiler is only half of the story. There is also Database Engine Tuning Advisor and these tools are the main tool set if you really want to optimize SQL queries - but optimizing SQL queries you don't have under your control is very hard and sometimes impossible.

Comment: If I remember correctly, LINQPad can show you the generated SQL of an Entity LINQ query.

Answer (score 4):

The [ToTraceString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx) method can do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you cast your IQueryable to a ObjectQuery, you can use the ToTraceString()-method to see the SQL query.

Comment: Didn't realize you can cast it down, great info. But I was looking for an app that will do this.

Comment: @Alwyn - Sorry, I have a bad habit of not reading the full question.

Comment: Don't worry it was my fault, for not being specific enough. Gave you a thumb's up, great answer.